# Create matrix from list in MS Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a list in MS Excel that looks like as follows:

```
A1 2
A2 3
A3 5
A4 1
```

I now want to make a matrix out of it, where every value adds to each other. Like this:

```
   A1 A2 A3 A4
A1 4  5  7  3
A2 5  6  8  4
A3 7  8  10 6
A4 3  4  6  2
```

Is there an easy way to create such a matrix? The only possible solution I have right now is to create the matrix manually. But my list consists of over 200 values and I have to create more matrices.

The Names (A1, A2 etc.) do not display in my sheet. I just used them for illustration.

Comment: Do A1,A2,A3,A4 display in Sheet? If yes, I created a sample by use this formula: **=SUMPRODUCT((($A$1:$A$4=$A7)+($A$1:$A$4=B$6))*($B$1:$B$4))** screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/ia4WdSo

Comment: A1 A2 ... do not display in the sheet, sorry I forgot to mention that. I just need the Matrix with the numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that the original data is on the worksheet with the name of `Sheet1` in A1:A4 range. Suppose that the result range is A1:D4 on another sheet.

If so, use formula

```
=INDIRECT("Sheet1!R" & ROW() & "C1",FALSE)+INDIRECT("Sheet1!R" & COLUMN() & "C1",FALSE)
```

For another destination range substract proper constants from ROW() and COLUMN() values in formula. For another source range - add proper constant to ROW() and COLUMN() and alter "C1" constant to "Cx" respectively.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I don't understand some parts of the formula, even after using Google to check what they mean: What does the R in Sheet1!R mean? And what does "C1", FALSE mean. And just to be sure, since my question was not clear: I have sheet1 with the numbers in "Column A Row 1" to "Column A Row x". And I have the second sheet where the matrix should appear. No names for the rows and columns needed.

Comment: *What does the R in Sheet1!R mean?* I use R1C1-style addressing. So the address for `A1` cell looks like `R1C1` - cell from Row=1 in Column=1. *what does "C1", FALSE mean.* I use INDIRECT() function. It can have 1 or 2 parameters, I use 2-parameter form. FALSE is 2nd parameter, it set R1C1 addressing style. 1st parameter is `"Sheet1!R" & ROW() & "C1"`, it builds an address. For example, if this formula is in a cell from row 2, it will be evaluated to `"Sheet1!R2C1"` - that mean it is a cell in row 2 and column 1 (A2 in notation familiar to you) on Sheet1 worksheet.

Comment: Ok I see. But if I copy your formula and change the name Sheet1 to the sheetname I use, it does not work. Excel tells me there's a problem with this formula and highlights "C1", FALSE.

Comment: Show the formula after your edition.

Comment: =INDIRECT("Grunddaten!R" & ROW() & "C1",FALSE)+INDIRECT("Grunddaten!R" & COLUMN() & "C1",FALSE)

Comment: Please insert 2 new worksheets named as Sheet1 and Sheet2 into your workbook and try to reproduce the model posted in your question using my formula. Is it working fine or error occures? If error - make Sheet2 active, open VBA editor (Alt-F11), open Immediate window and execute `Range("A1").Formula="=INDIRECT("=INDIRECT(""Sheet1!R"" & ROW() & ""C1"",FALSE)+INDIRECT(""Sheet1!R"" & COLUMN() & ""C1"",FALSE)"`. Is it working?

Comment: First method does not work, same error as before. In which window should I type the command in the VBA editor? I double clicked on Sheet2 and typed in the command, but I get the error "Expected: list separator or )

Comment: *First method does not work, same error as before.* Is your Excel english or national? *In which window should I type the command in the VBA editor?* Activate Sheet2. Press Alt-F11 - the VBA editor window opens. Press Ctrl-G - the Immediate window occures. Copy `Range("A1").Formula="=INDIRECT(""Sheet1!R"" & ROW() & ""C1"",FALSE)+INDIRECT(""Sheet1!R"" & COLUMN() & ""C1"",FALSE)"` (there is a misprint in previous comment) into it and press Enter. Look the formula in A1 cell on Sheet2 if no error.

Comment: Excel is in english. Using the Immediate window I get still displayed the error: "Expected: list separator or )"

Comment: @gHupf Look the example on [Google](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IcVCH3ZZsn3Tx7EyuMHNOWIxJp7QrrmtqhWGJtq5ZMU/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: That perfectly works, thanks! In your google formula the comma behind "C1" is a semicolon. That's the reason it did not work.

Comment: @gHupf Semicolon instead of comma is an effect of a example file locale (it's Russian). If your Excel needs semicolon, your locale is not en-us too.